# Spyder does not show lists and arrays in variable explorer

Tags: python, list, spyder

i don't really know why, but Spyder is not able to show lists or arrays in the variable explorer anymore. Do you have the same problem, any fixes? I have that problem on two computers.

Example:

```
CSV = []
for x in os.listdir(location):
    if x.split(".")[-1] =="CSV":
        CSV.append(location+x)
CSV = np.array(CSV)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Menu (Tools->Preferences->Variable Explorer) Shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P)

Disable all the filters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure "Exclude capitalized references" in "Tools->Preferences->Variable Explorer" is not marked. The reason you don't see your list in variable explorer is that your list name starts with capital letters and Spyder considers it a capitalized reference. If you define it as for example 'my_csv' or 'aCSV' instead of 'CSV', you don't need to change the setting and it will be fine.