# Spyder: variable explorer does not show variable for connected remote kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, spyder, remote-server, explorer

Spyder variable explorer works fine for a local kernel; however, it does not work for the remote kernel. Indeed, the connection to the kernel and running the codes works well but non of the variables are shown in the varibale explorer.

Here is some information:

Python 3.6.8 64-bit | Qt 5.9.4 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64

I also unmarked all filters in "Preferences>Variable explorer>Filter" and followed the posts below but no improvement.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7850

[Spyder does not show lists and arrays in variable explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788286/spyder-does-not-show-lists-and-arrays-in-variable-explorer)

- spyder-kernels is installed in both local and remote machines.
- the connection is through SSH.
- Spyder is up to date.

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I tested this and it's working as expected for me. Please read [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) on how to properly connect to remote kernels.

Comment: Carlos, it is not working in ubuntu 18.04 under anaconda ve, spyder 3.3.4, ipython 7.5.0 (python 3.7.3). with vars() I can get the right variables but variable explorer does not show

Comment: Same problem with ubuntu 18.04, Spyder 3.3.6, IPython 7.4.0 (Python 3.7.3)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, objects didn't show up in spyder - variable explorer, fixed it by creating a new env and fresh install for spyder kernels

Create new env

```
conda create --name python3test python=3
```

Activate env

```
conda activate python3test
```

Install kernel for spyder

```
conda install spyder-kernels
```

Generate new kernel and then quit - store kernel name

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console
```

Connect to kernel

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console -f kernel-XXXX.json
```

Download kernel json file (for me was to Win), launch Spyder and connect to kernel.

Comment: This solution, although with minor deviations from the official documentation, does not work for me (Ubuntu 18.04, Spyder 3.3.6 and Ipython 4.3.1)